# File Upload For Custom Magento 1.5.0.1 Dataflow

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have made a custom Magento 1.5.0.1 Dataflow module using this guide: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/customizing-magento-dataflow-import-of-custom-data

Everything is working well, however, is it possible to use a file upload rather than needing to manually upload a file via FTP and specifying the file location?